# Linux mint man pages require sudo when pager is neovim

Tags: linux, permissions, man, nvim

If I `sudo man` it works fine, otherwise I'm getting

```
~$ man ls
fuse: mount failed: Permission denied

Cannot mount AppImage, please check your FUSE setup.
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage 
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option. 
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE 
for more information
open dir error: No such file or directory
```

for reference, setting the `MANPAGER` as per neovim help

`export MANPAGER='nvim +Man!'`

`:Man` command works fine from inside nvim.

Comment: The title should be a summary of the question, not the first line. Also tell us which OS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why this happens with MANPAGER, but following the suggestion in your error message, I believe this works:

```
export MANPAGER='nvim --appimage-extract-and-run -c "set ft=man"'
```

**UPDATE**:

The previous solution is not working anymore in neovim >= v0.6.1. The following is the [recommended](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/14090#issuecomment-913837694) approach:

```
export MANPAGER='nvim +Man!'
```

Comment: thank you for that. Unfortunatelly my linux machine is long gone so I can't confirm that this works.

Comment: The recommended approach (from `:help Man`) you list is the exact same line the OP had in the question. The error persists, at least on Ubuntu 22.04.